# CKEditor Data Bind in asp.net core mvc

Tags: ckeditor, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created a EditController to fetch and edit the contents of my database in asp.net core project. The Controller is given below:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(MyObject model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await  _myObjectRepository.UpdateMsg(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I've used the following script tag to reference the ckeditor and kept it on Edit.cshtml.

Inside the form tag I've put the following lines of code to display the editor and display the data from the database inside the editor.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Body" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <textarea asp-for="Body"  id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace('Body');</script>
```

I've no problem displaying the data from database to the editor. But as I try to change the text in the editor, no text would be present in the database.

So tested the code without using the editor i.e. I simply used  tag instead of the CKEditor, with usual razor attributes and it worked fine. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you have a property in the MyObject class to store the content of the CKEditor. Lets suppose "ckEditorVar" is the property  to store the ckeditor content. Following code works for me. I hope it will work for you too.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(MyObject model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             await _myObjectRepository.UpdateMsg(new MyObject 
            {
                ckeditorVar = Request.Form["editor1"].ToString(),

             });

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks David for the answer. This method save the content with the html tags. Can we remove the html tags while storing to the database?